# Updating the balance of after each withdrawal or deposit in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to show update balance after each deposit or withdraw request. Also, if withdraw amount is more than current balance, then I want to show the message that says insufficient money and also show the cuurent balance.

Deposit – add the amount that is deposited to the account and output a success
message and the new balance.
Withdraw – attemot to perform a withdraw with the amount requested. The account
must have the as much or more than the requested withdraw amoiun to allow the
withdrawal. If the user has less than the amoiunt requested, give an “Insufficient Funds”
message and do not allow the withdrawa. If the account has as much or more than the
requested amohnt, perform the withdrawal by subtracting fornt he balance.Either way,
re-print the balance of the account

here is my HTML and CSS and also my so far javasript code

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    background-image: url("https://newton.ncc.edu/gansonj/ite154/img/bank-bkg.jpg");
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: right;
    color: #008B8B;
}

#pagewrap {
    border: 8px #EEB76B solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 600px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #212121;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto; 
}


#title {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    border-bottom: 7px #EEB76B double;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #EEB76B;
    text-align: center;
}

.formtext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bank-action {
    border: 3px #EEB76B solid;
    background-color: #310B0B;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #EEB76B;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.bank-action:hover {
    border: 3px #000000 solid;
    background-color: #EEB76B;
    color: #351F39;
}

#output {
    height: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
    border: 8px #EEB76B solid;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.spacer {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#amount {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px #EEB76B solid;
}
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var intamount =500;
    $("#output").html( intamount )


    $(".bank-action").on("click" , function(){
        var amount = parseFloat($("#amount").val() );
        var msg= "";
        var addmoney = intamount + amount;
        var withdrawmoney = addmoney - amount;
        
        
        

        var money = $(this).attr("id");

        if (money == "deposit"){
            msg+= "<div> Your deposit of $" + amount + " was successful</div>";
            msg+= "<div> Your Current Balance is $" + addmoney + "</div>";

        }
        else {
            if (amount >= intamount ){
                msg+= "<div> Due to insufficient balance,your request can't be successful</div>";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current balance is $" + addmoney + "</div>";

            }
            else {
                msg+= "<div> Your withdraw of $" + amount + " was successful</div>";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current balance is $" + withdrawmoney + "</div>";
            }
           

        }

        $("#output").html(msg);

        


    }); // end event handler

    
} );  // ends document.ready

</script> 
</head>
<body>

<div id="pagewrap">

    <div id="title">ITE154 Bank of Garden City</div>
    
    <div id="formwrap" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    
        <form>
        
            <div class="spacer formtext">
                    Enter transaction amount
            </div>
            <div class="spacer">
                    <input type="text" id="amount">
            </div>
        
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="bank-action" id="deposit" value="Deposit">
                <input type="button" class="bank-action" id="withdraw" value="Withdraw">
            </div>

    
        <div class="spacer formtext">
                Current Account Balance
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        
    </div> <!-- ends div#formwrap -->
    
</div> <!-- ends div#pagewrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?

Comment: I am having problem with updated current balanvce after deposit or withdraw

Comment: Write a function `updateBalance` and call it at the end of `deposit` and `withdraw`.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a *Deposit* and *Widraw* function, you need an `array` that will store your *deposit* and *widraw* detail.

Also I don't understand this *"Insufficient Funds"* if not enough balance since you declare on your message *"Due to insufficient balance,your request can't be successful"*. So I assume that this will show if the user widraw more that the current balance.

**"Insufficient Funds"** - Will show if user widraw more than the current balance.

**"Due to insufficient balance,your request can't be successful"** - Will show if the user widraw same value as the current balance.

I re-make some of your functions, so I hope this could help you in some ways.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var intamount = 500;
    $("#output").html( intamount )
    $(".bank-action").on("click" , function(){
        var amount = parseFloat($("#amount").val() );
        var msg = "";
        var my_deposit = [];
        var my_withdraw = [];
        var money = $(this).attr("id");
        
        if (money == "deposit"){
            if (!amount){
                msg+= "<div> Input the amount to deposit.";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current Balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
            }else{
                msg+= "<div> Your deposit of $" + amount + " was successful</div>";
                intamount += amount;
                my_deposit.push(intamount);
                msg+= "<div> Your Current Balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
                parseFloat($("#amount").val("") );
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!amount){
                msg+= "<div> Input the amount to widraw. </div>";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current Balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
            }else if (amount > intamount ){
                msg+= "<div> Insufficient Funds </div>";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
                parseFloat($("#amount").val("") );
            }else if (amount == intamount ){
                msg+= "<div> Due to insufficient balance,your request can't be successful</div>";
                msg+= "<div> Your Current balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
                parseFloat($("#amount").val("") );
            }else{
                msg+= "<div> Your withdraw of $" + amount + " was successful</div>";
                intamount -= amount;
                my_withdraw.push(intamount);
                msg+= "<div> Your Current balance is $" + intamount + "</div>";
                parseFloat($("#amount").val("") );
            }
        }
        $("#output").html(msg);
    }); // end event handler
} );  // ends document.ready
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("https://newton.ncc.edu/gansonj/ite154/img/bank-bkg.jpg");
    font-family: arial;
    text-align: right;
    color: #008B8B;
}

#pagewrap {
    border: 8px #EEB76B solid;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 800px;
    min-height: 600px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #212121;
    margin: 40px auto 0px auto; 
}


#title {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    border-bottom: 7px #EEB76B double;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #EEB76B;
    text-align: center;
}

.formtext {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.bank-action {
    border: 3px #EEB76B solid;
    background-color: #310B0B;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #EEB76B;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.bank-action:hover {
    border: 3px #000000 solid;
    background-color: #EEB76B;
    color: #351F39;
}

#output {
    height: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
    border: 8px #EEB76B solid;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.spacer {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#amount {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px #EEB76B solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="pagewrap">
    <div id="title">ITE154 Bank of Garden City</div>
    <div id="formwrap" style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <form>
            <div class="spacer formtext">
                Enter transaction amount
            </div>
            <div class="spacer">
                <input type="text" id="amount">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="bank-action" id="deposit" value="Deposit">
                <input type="button" class="bank-action" id="withdraw" value="Withdraw">
            </div>
            <div class="spacer formtext">
                Current Account Balance
            </div>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- ends div#formwrap -->
</div> <!-- ends div#pagewrap -->
```